# is there a way to set env variables within azure storage account

Tags: azure, environment-variables, cloud, azure-storage

I've enabled <kbd>Static website</kbd> within azure storage account, deployed to it a simple React webapp within `$web` container that has been created automatically just after enabling `static website`.

I am wondering is there a way to setup environment variables within azure storage account, and is there an alternative to do so, and how?

Comment: If you are talking about the React environment variables from a standard React template; No. When you build your project the environment variables will be placed directly into your source code. So they should already be incorporated in the files before you upload them to the storage container.

Comment: @NotFound Yep, that's what I do, I just wondered if it is possible but it seems there is no way, so the best way is to store the env variables within `.env` or in my case within Github action secrets, build it then deploy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to set env variables within azure storage account?

I agree with Not Found's comment. In Azure Storage static website hosting, there is no way to set environment variables as part of the static website feature itself.

As for the approach, if you need to use environment variables, you can store them within a `.env` file or in a secure location, such as Github action secrets, build your project, and then deploy it to Azure Storage.

For example, you can store the value of the environment variable REACT_APP_API_KEY as a GitHub Actions secret and reference it in your workflow file as follows, if your React app needs it:

```
- name: Build and deploy React app
  env:
    REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_ENV_VAR }}
  run: |
    npm install @azure/storage-blob
    npm run build
    az storage blob upload-batch --destination '$web' --source build
```

In the [app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#environment-variables-and-app-settings-in-azure-app-service), certain settings are available to the deployment or runtime environment as environment variables, but in Azure storage, there is no way to set environment variables.

Comment: Why store the key as a secret when its visible to anyone accessing the website?